# Why does the button size increase when I increase font size/change font type in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

```
self.button_decimal = Button(root, text=".", command=lambda: self.decimal(),
                             width="9", height="2", bg="steelBlue", font="Serif 12")
```

If I remove `font="Serif 12"` then everything is normal but when I add `font="Serif 12"` it does change the font size but it also increases/decreases the size of the button depending on what size you chose.

My questions are, 1.why does this happen?
2.How can I increase the font size and **NOT** the button size using the `font=""` argument?

Comment: Why is the button changing size bad? Are you trying to create a button with text that is partially chopped off?

Comment: its part of a calculator application and all buttons need to be same size.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe reducing the padding inside the button might work for me. I'm not sure.

Comment: If your real goal is to make all the buttons a uniform size, there are ways to accomplish that. For example, assuming you're using `grid`, you can use the `uniform` and `minsize` options to force rows and columns to be the same size.

Comment: I'm so sorry I replied so late, but i really appreciate the fact that your trying to help :) I will soon try those uniform and minimize options. But just in case it doesn't work can you always keep this thread in mind so that I can refer back here and maybe you can suggest something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.why does this happen?**

It happened because that's how they are designed to work. Buttons are sized relative to the font used by the button. 99.9% of the time this is the exact right thing to do. Without this, if you specify a large font, the text will be chopped off by the edges of the button.

**2.How can I increase the font size and NOT the button size using the font="" argument?**

You can't. See point #1.

Though, that's not 100% true. There are a couple options that work on some platforms (on OSX, for example, I think there is literally nothing you can do).

You can add an image to the button, in which case the `width` and `height` parameters will be treated as pixel values rather than a number of characters.

You can force a button to a specific size by providing constraints on the button via the geometry managers. I imagine this would be easiest with `place` since it has a `width` and a `height` attribute. However, it likely won't give you good results unless the font you switch to is nearly identical to the original font.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the "You can force a button to a specific size by providing constraints on the button via the geometry managers" solution.

Comment: @ZaidA: not in the comment section. That's a completely different question.

Comment: I apologize for that.